# dataTable-popupPanel master-detail doesn't save edited values

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, popup, richfaces

I have a list of products which is displayed in datatable ,and want to edit a particular row from the datatable in a pop up as described below

A datatable with all the employee details, each row has edit button.On clicking the edit button the new pop-up should be displayed with the existing information of particular clicked product and after editing, the changes must be reflected for that particular object in the list as well in datatable.

I am struggling for it but i could not save the changes in edited product. when the pop up is opened, l can see the selected item properties but when I changed the properties, nothing changes. 
here is the my jsf code.

```
<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
    <h:dataTable id="table1" value="#{productBean.products}" var="item"
        styleClass="resultTable" headerClass="resultTableHeader"
        rowClasses="resultTableRow">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Part#" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.partNumber}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Product Description" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.description}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>  
        <a4j:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{productBean.setEditItem(item)}" oncomplete="#{rich:component('popup')}.show()"> </a4j:commandButton>

                    <rich:popupPanel  id="popup" modal="true" resizeable="true"
                onmaskclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide()">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Edit property of the product" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="controls">
                    <h:outputLink value="#"
                        onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide(); return false;">
                      X
                  </h:outputLink>
                </f:facet>
                <!-- editProduct ı burda item yerine kullan  -->                    
                <table style="align: center;">
                    <tr>
                        <td><h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <h:outputText value="Description"></h:outputText>
                                <h:inputText value="#{productBean.item.description}"></h:inputText>
                            </h:panelGrid></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <h:outputText value="Part Number"></h:outputText>
                                <h:inputText value="#{item.partNumber}"></h:inputText>
                            </h:panelGrid></td>
                    </tr>
                </table> 
                    <a4j:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{productBean.actionEditProductsFromDatabase(item)}"  execute="@popup"/>
                    <a4j:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('editPane')}.hide(); return false;" />
            </rich:popupPanel>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

</a4j:outputPanel>

</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the *Placement* callout in the RichFaces Component Reference:

http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-Panels-richpopupPanel

> The `<rich:popupPanel>` component is usually rendered in front of any
>   other objects on the page. This is achieved by attaching the component
>   to the `<body>` element of the page, and setting a very high "z-index"
>   (the stack order of the object). This approach is taken because
>   relatively-positioned elements could still overlap the pop-up panel if
>   they exist at higher levels of the DOM hierarchy, even if their
>   z-index is less than the `<rich:popupPanel>` component.
>
> If the `<rich:popupPanel>` is to participate in submitting child
>   components/behaviors, then a **form element must be nested within the
>   `<rich:popupPanel>`**. Alternatively, if no overlapping elements exist,
>   the `<rich:popupPanel>` component can be reattached to its original DOM
>   element by **setting domElementAttachment to either parent or form**.